# WEPopover's background just disappeared

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

So I am using WEPopover for one of my projects and everything seemed to be going smooth until xcode begin acting really funny. 
I restarted my computer and now the background of my popOver just doesn't show up any more. I've tried cleaning i've tried downloading old revisions nothing seems to work. If i open up the WEPopover demo app it works fine however, the one I have imported just isn't working right.

Comment: if you are using an image as a background check whether it's name is written correctly, and also while adding file's to the X-code make sure to check the copy items.